# Page URL determines page content? "?=NameHere"

Tags: php, html

I extremely apologise in advance for the wording of the question, if an admin could word it better feel free too. I'm probably going to find this difficult to explain.

I want to create a page which uses a part of the URL to create a "custom" part of the page.

For example www.example.com/hello?=Derek

And the title would read "Hello Derek" or whatever you put after "?=". I know a few websites use this and I was wondering how I would go about doing this.

Comment: Your question is crystal clear and this is PHP101. The [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) array will have your variables.

Comment: Ah okay, I know nothing of PHP, its a thing for me to learn this year :P Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JayBlanchard Sir, `hello?=Derek` does not look like valid URL..

Comment: You're right in this case @RayonDabre The query string should be `/?hello=Derek` with 'Derek' being in `$_GET['hello']`.

Comment: If you know *nothing* of PHP, a beginners tutorial might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking of query parameters, they're of the form `key=value`, separated by `&` for multiple parameters and by `?` from the normal page URL. So in your case it would be `www.example.com/hello?name=Derek`.

As to how to display it in PHP, the following should do it:

```
<?php
   echo 'Hello ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["name"]);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If `www.example.com?hello=Derek` is acceptible to you, you can use the following code in your index.php:

```
<?php
  // Initialize the name variable, so it can be used easily.
  $name = '';

  // Check if a name was given. If so, assign it to the variable.
  // The leading space is there to have a space between 'Hello' and the name.
  // If you don't pass a name, the text will just say Hello! without space.
  if (isset($_GET['hello'])) { 
    $name = ' ' . $_GET['hello'];
  }

// Personal opinion: Don't echo big chunks of HTML. Instead, close the PHP tag, and 
// output the plain HTML using < ?= ... ? > to insert the variables you've initialized 
// in the code above.
?>
<h2>Hello<?=$name?>!</h2>
```

Comment: You should mention that they should sanitize/validate the input.

Comment: Should they? Depends on what you want. You *could* 'inject' HTML in the name, but even then, it's not like any server side code or queries are executed.

Comment: Good point, I just think that as the user is a *beginner* they should learn good from the start.

Comment: That's why I added the initialization of a variable, the checking if the query string argument was set, an example on how to echo PHP variables in plain HTML code, and extensive comments to explain all of them. ;-)